# Don't know how to get money out of smart wallet

Tags: contract-debugging, selfdestruct, smart-contract-wallets

Three years ago I bought some Ethereum.
Little as I knew I put some of it in a smart contract.

The smart contract says it has 0.21 ether.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x6Ca3EB0184E652fa3b959bfA6632ab90cda401ab

But it seems to be self destructed.

[image: Self destruct]

It also tells me that the money is transferred to my account.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54e90b0f32993677a1e93945b13d9668f8db536735f22dab0d5db43f9737ac8c#internal

[image: Transfer to account]

But when I look into my account I can't see the ether added to it.
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf958cf4b12c5f2b0ccf1b386cef873298197f45e

**My question is:
How to i retrieve the money from my smart contract. And get it in my account.**

*I can access my account with a wallet.
But I don't have any more information about the smart contract other than the address.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what's happened here, but...

The smart contract was indeed self-destructed - via the `kill()` function - in the transaction you've pointed to ([this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54e90b0f32993677a1e93945b13d9668f8db536735f22dab0d5db43f9737ac8c) one).

During the self-destruct the ETH in the contract was sent to your wallet address, again which [you've pointed to](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54e90b0f32993677a1e93945b13d9668f8db536735f22dab0d5db43f9737ac8c#internal).

At this point the contract's state would have been wiped. It's important to note that [you shouldn't interact with a destroyed contract](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x54e90b0f32993677a1e93945b13d9668f8db536735f22dab0d5db43f9737ac8c).

However, the next transaction from your wallet ([this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x847f484fde2b9fb47028368a6d7872b443adcd5b71cb64a118ecc129c7f468ee) one) seems to have then attempted to call the `kill()` function a second time, which won't work on a self-destructed contract.

What's more unfortunate is that [you sent your 0.21 ETH](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x847f484fde2b9fb47028368a6d7872b443adcd5b71cb64a118ecc129c7f468ee#statechange) with that second `kill()` transaction, meaning the ETH is back in the contract.

I'm suspecting that the ETH is now stuck, and that further calls to `kill()` to try to recover the ETH will fall on deaf ears: the contract is no longer call-able.